# mustache.js: ok to add entire page as mustache container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I am trying to use mustache.js to deliver a multi-language version of my website. Therefore I am wondering if it is ok to add a `<div id="mainContainer">` inside my `<body>` tag that contains all HTML elements of the page and then all mustache tags inside that big container via the usual:

```
var template = $('#mainContainer').html(); 
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, mustacheData);
$('#mainContainer').html(html);
```

It seems to work but I am wondering if there are pitfalls here (e.g. performance of reading, rendering and setting html of an entire page?). I have a dynamic bootstrap page with a couple of pages. The `mustacheData` would obtained the localized strings from a server in a specific language.

Comment: if you're concerned about SEO or analytics at all, the single page app style like this can be a drawback. you might want to consider subdomains or just different directories like www.mysite.com/en/; www.mysite.com/es/ etc.